# Update table data from view in PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I am having an entity-relationship model in which I am trying to respect the normalization rules. But in order to work into QGIS through PostGIS and have only relevant data at the moment, I would like to work through some views, display these views into QGIS and possibly update the corresponding table according to the modifications made in the view.

For example I have three tables where cable is the one containing the datas I have to work with, modele_cable a reference table (weak entity) containing some informations which would fill the view, and type_cable a weak entity of modele_table, also containing some information relevant in the view. As such :

```
CREATE TABLE test.cable(
      id_cable serial NOT NULL,
      id_modele_cable integer,
      geom geometry(MultiLineString,2154),
      CONSTRAINT prk_constraint_cable PRIMARY KEY (id_cable),
      CONSTRAINT fk_cable_id_modele_cable FOREIGN KEY (id_modele_cable)
          REFERENCES test.modele_cable (id_modele_cable)
    );
    CREATE TABLE test.modele_cable(
      id_modele_cable serial NOT NULL,
      id_type_cable integer,
      CONSTRAINT prk_constraint_modele_cable PRIMARY KEY (id_modele_cable),
      CONSTRAINT fk_modele_cable_id_type_cable FOREIGN KEY (id_type_cable)
          REFERENCES test.type_cable (id_type_cable)
    );
    CREATE TABLE test.type_cable(
      id_type_cable serial NOT NULL,
      nb_fo integer,
      CONSTRAINT prk_constraint_type_cable PRIMARY KEY (id_type_cable)
    );
    CREATE VIEW public.cable_ok AS 
     SELECT cable.id_cable,
        cable.designation,
        type_cable.nb_fo,
        cable.geom
       FROM test.cable
         LEFT JOIN test.modele_cable ON cable.id_modele_cable=modele_cable.id_modele_cable
         LEFT JOIN test.type_cable ON type_cable.id_type_cable=modele_cable.id_type_cable;
```

I didn't find any information on how to do what I want, nor if it is even possible, and if not what could be a workaround. I tried to make a trigger which would detect the modification in the view in PostGIS, and update the table 'cable' accordingly, but I didn't manage to do so (I successfully only once created a trigger in another context before, and quite painfully). I also noticed that it is not possible to update a view manually inside the table of the view (which sounds logical since it is a view).

Does anyone have any clue, direction, help, experience that could help me solve this problem ?

**UPDATE** here is a trigger as I tried to implement it :

```
create or replace function tout.update_cable_view() returns trigger as 
    $body$
    begin
    select modele_cable.id_modele_cable
    into cable.id_modele_cable
    from test.cable
    inner join test.modele_cable on cable.id_modele_cable=modele_cable.id_modele_cable 
    inner join test.type_cable on modele_cable.id_type_cable=type_cable.id_type_cable, 
    public.cable_ok
    where cable_ok.nb_fo=type_cable.nb_fo;
    return null;
    end;
    $body$
    language plpgsql;

    create trigger t_update_cable_view
    instead of insert or update on public.cable_ok
    for each row
    execute procedure tout.update_cable_view();
```

**UPDATE 2** here is a trigger function which should be working, but is not :

```
create or replace function tout.update_cable_view() returns trigger as 
$body$
begin   
update test.cable
set id_modele_cable = (select id_modele_cable from test.modele_cable 
inner join test.type_cable on 

modele_cable.id_type_cable=type_cable.id_type_cable
    where new.nb_fo=type_cable.nb_fo and old.id_cable=new.id_cable);
return new;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. An [updatable view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-views.html#RULES-VIEWS-UPDATE)? If so, you tried to write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger for it, but failed? Please add more context and your failed tries.

Comment: I want that when I update some information in the view layer in QGIS, or when I create a new tuple or delete one in the view in QGIS, the table 'cable' get updated accordingly. I edited my original post with a failed try of a trigger I tried to implement. I guess a big problem is that there is no 'new' variable in the trigger function...

Comment: The `NEW` "row" is defined in the `INSTEAD OF` triggers too. Also, you may want to `RETURN NEW` ([instead of `NULL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) -- *`INSTEAD OF` triggers can return null to signal that they did not perform any updates, and that the rest of the operation for this row should be skipped*) -- You really should **not** `SELECT` from the view, which is being inserted/updated.

Comment: what your updatable view must do, is: lookup&fixup the `id_modele_cable` FK from the `modele_cable` -> `type_cable.nb_fo` field, given the `nb_fo` in the new view tuple. This can be hard, because there *could* be multiple `modele_cable` rows pointing to the same `type_cable` tuple.

Comment: @pozs I am sorry, I cannot say I understand what to do. Before I had my function return new and it didn't work either. Anyway I get an error in the `INTO` statement saying I cannot put cable.id_modele_cable. Did you ever face that kind of need like mine ? And if yes could you provide me an example ? I am still trying to wrap my head around this trigger thing.

Comment: @wildplasser to be honest there isn't just the nb_fo, there are other fields in my real case which combined refer to a single modele_cable possibility. So I shouldn't have a problem about possible multiple rows.

Comment: @GuiOmClair you'll need multiple `INSERT INTO underlying_table VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2, ...)` statements f.ex. in the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger. You shouldn't "read" from the view inside that trigger, use the `NEW` variable instead.

Comment: @pozs ok, and, let's say it is for an update more than an insert, what do I put in my `INTO` statement ?

Comment: @GuiOmClair there is no `INTO` clause of an `UPDATE` statement. You should use a similar logic: `UPDATE underlying_table SET col1 = NEW.col1, col2 = NEW.col2, ... WHERE col1 = OLD.col1` (if `col1` if the primary key f.ex.)

Comment: *... but my actual problem is larger than this ...*

Comment: Ok, I have a trigger function that seems to be operational, but still I get an error message saying that "views reading many tables or views are not automatically available for writing" with a hint "to activate the update of the view, provide a trigger INSTEAD OF UPDATE or a rule ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD without condition". I updated my original post to show the new trigger function.

Comment: You also need to update the other *native* fields in `cable`. And you should refer to `new.` as often as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way of doing what I wanted using a rule. My guess is that PostgreSQL doesn't allow the saving of the view. With an `INSTEAD` rule it does not try to save the view, and instead update the original table, updating automatically the view then. Here is the piece of code, for an update :

```
create rule "_test_rule" as
on update to public.cable_ok
do instead update test.cable
set id_modele_cable = (select id_modele_cable from test.modele_cable 
inner join test.type_cable on modele_cable.id_type_cable=type_cable.id_type_cable
where new.nb_fo=type_cable.nb_fo and new.id_cable=cable.id_cable)
where old.id_cable=cable.id_cable;
```